# Salesforce Mutiselect apex:selectlist and javascript remoting

Tags: dynamic-visualforce, javascript-remoting

Can anyone provide me any example or code snippet how to use multiselect apex:selectlist and javascript remoting.

Regards

Comment: It would be helpful if you can elaborate the use case as to what you are really trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Rajiv..I have two apex:selectlist multiselect. One continent and one country.when continent is selected country will populated and when country is seleted, states will be populated on separate pageblock.I want to achieve this using javascript remoting..

Comment: You'll want to refer to the [JavaScript Remoting Section](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting.htm) of the VisualForce Developer's Guide which includes example code. If you run into specific issues in your code I'm confident people will be willing to help. JS remoting is being replaced with Remote Objects which is covered in the same section of the Guide.